# Best way to convert an array from Core Data to a JSON string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have some data in Core Data that I want to convert to a string so that I can send it back to my web server. This is the code I have so far:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *unfinishedTime = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *timeEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TimeEntries" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[unfinishedTime setEntity:timeEntity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timeStart != nil AND timeEnd != nil"];
[unfinishedTime setPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *timeArray = [context executeFetchRequest:unfinishedTime error:&error];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:timeArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It is giving me an error on the NSData line. From what I can tell, timeArray has 5 objects in it. I'm sure this is a pretty simple mistake and I could be going about this the total wrong way.

Comment: I wrote toDictionary methods for all my core data models.  It makes it easy when I need to convert them to JSON or log them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [`NSJSONSerialization`'s documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)...

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary. All objects are
>   instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull. All
>   dictionary keys are instances of NSString. Numbers are not NaN or
>   infinity.

In your case the top-level object is an `NSArray` but all objects are instances of `NSManagedObject` (or a custom subclass of that, if that's how you've setup your project).

Probably the easiest fix is this:

```
unfinishedTime.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
```

That way Core Data will return you an array of dictionaries rather than an array of managed objects, which are objects the JSON serialiser knows how to serialise.

Comment: Interesting, I was trying to turn the array into a dictionary but I wasn't sure how. I'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: That did seems to work however I have another error: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSDate)'. My Core Data has a couple date fields and JSON can't handle them. Is there an easy way to convert them or do I have to loop through the array and do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put " kNilOptions " option instead of " NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted"